# How to solve the out of memory exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm developing a Winforms application. This code contains it to save an image to a SQL Server  table. But sometimes a `Out of memory` exception happens when I'm returning the binary data from the table to display the image.

This is my code to convert image before save.

```
openImage.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";

if (openImage.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(openImage.FileName);         
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;      
    lblImgInfo.Text = openImage.FileName;
    FRM_ImageViewer imgver = new FRM_ImageViewer(openImage.FileName);
    imgver.Show();

    string strFn = openImage.FileName;
    FileInfo fiImage = new FileInfo(strFn);

    long  m_lImageFileLength =fiImage.Length;
    byte[] m_barrImg = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(m_lImageFileLength)];

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    int iBytesRead = fs.Read(m_barrImg, 0,Convert.ToInt32(m_lImageFileLength));
    fs.Close();
}
```

and  this is my code to retrieve the image from the database

```
// DTSelectedJobs is a DataTable  in csharp.
byte[] barrImg = (byte[])DTSelectedJobs.Rows[0].ItemArray[11];
string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(strfn, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
fs2.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);
fs2.Flush();
fs2.Close();
FRM_ImageViewer imgvwr = new FRM_ImageViewer(strfn);
imgvwr.Show();
```

Can someone please give me an advice how to find the error?

Comment: `Bitmap` inherits from [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) which is Disposable, you need to dispose of your bitmap.

Comment: @Sayse and the `FileStream`

Comment: `this code contains it to save an image to sql server table.` **WHOA, STOP RIGHT THERE.** Never save images to a database!!

Comment: Where (which line) exactly the exception happens?

Comment: Are you doing anything with `m_barrImg`? Also assuming `FRM_ImageViewer` opens the file, combined with the `Bitmap` created for `pictureBox1`, you'll have three copies of the same image in memory. What exactly are you converting?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Im converting  the image selected  by  open file dialog  an put  in into m_barrImg. could u please explain me what  are 3 copies of same image in my code?

Comment: thanks all . The exception is comming from here   byte[] barrImg = (byte[])DTSelectedJobs.Rows[0].ItemArray[11]; when the   DTSelectedJobs.Rows[0].ItemArray[11] is empty.

Comment: @HasankaRathnayake With "converting an image" people usually mean changing the type (bmp to jpg). Regarding the multiple copies: I don't know how to help you if you don't understand my previous comment :S

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I'm sorry, I did not get it correctly. I mean transforming .jpg or .jpeg or .gif or .bmp to binary for  save in a table.

Answer (score 2):

`Bitmap` inherits from [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) which is Disposable, you need to dispose of your bitmap.

```
using(var bmp = new Bitmap(openImage.FileName))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

As DGibbs notes, you need to do the same for FileStream

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(strFn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                              FileShare.Read))
    int iBytesRead = fs.Read(m_barrImg, 0,Convert.ToInt32(m_lImageFileLength));
```

Comment: While I agree, does this answer the question? OP says he gets the error when reading the image form the database.

Comment: @DavidG - Anything that is a memory leak will be contributing, again there is a file stream in the second snippet which should receive the same treatment

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a memory leak (I would assume the GC would tidy that stuff up eventually) though it is memory inefficient. My concern is what is happening inside the `FRM_ImageViewer` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with `winforms` so bear with me but this looks incorrect to me.

You create a `strfn`:

```
string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
```

And then initialize an image viewer with... a date/time string?

```
FRM_ImageViewer imgvwr = new FRM_ImageViewer(strfn);
```

Seems like `barrImg` is what should be in the ctor here?

Also, `FileStream` implements the `IDisposable` interface so should be ideally wrapped in a using block:

```
using(FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(strfn, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs2.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);
    FRM_ImageViewer imgvwr = new FRM_ImageViewer(strfn);
    imgvwr.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's almost an year since the question was asked but let me share my thoughts since there is not an answer yet

> Out of memory exception was thrown because there is not enough memory
>   available for your application or your application is using too much
>   memory than available.

I would check the following to find why the application is using too much memory

1) Make sure table returns only required data. Because size of an image is large. If your database returns a large result then, the result set may use several MB's of memory.

Assuming you are trying to view an image saved in data base, if you are displaying **n** images then query for the specific records.

2) Make sure you are disposing all the disposable objects like Image, Bitmap,Stream, FileStream, Pen, etc., because it may cause memory leak in your application

3) Use a memory profiler to check for memory leaks in the application.